# Regular expression to find whether a string has sub string and ends with another sub string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have requirement to return true if a substring is found in the string and which will end with some other string.

means if i have string like below, then the regx should return true because it has Upper case `US` in the string and it is ending with `.properties`

```
/sap/m/messagebundle_en_US.properties
```

My strings are as follows

**EG:-**

```
/sap/m/messagebundle_en_US.properties -- true
/sap/m/messagebundle_US_en.properties -- true
/sap/m/messagebundle_us_en.properties -- false(not upper case US)
```

I am poor in regx. I googled and succeeded in finding a regx which will check for ending of string.

```
/.*.properties$/.test(".properties");
```

but i want a single regx to find both the things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
/US.*\.properties$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jN4rN3/2)